# Do I need to create a new variable to store result of merge sorted list sequence?

Tags: algorithm, list, merge, sequence, sorting

I think I've done the right thing by not creating a new topic. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

I've been given a question where I need to merge two sorted list-based sequences:

```
S1 = (1,5,8,12) S2 = (7,9,11,18)
```

1.

```
S1 = (5,8,12)
S2 = (7,9,11,18)
? = 1
```

2.

```
S1 = (8,12)
S2 = (7,9,11,18)
? = 1, 5
```

3.

```
S1 = (8,12)
S2 = (9,11,18)
? = 1, 5, 7
```

4.

```
S1 = (12)
S2 = (9,11,18)
? = 1, 5, 7, 8
```

5.

```
S1 = (12)
S2 = (11,18)
? = 1, 5, 7, 8, 9
```

6.

```
S1 = (12)
S2 = (18)
? = 1, 5, 7, 8, 9, 11
```

7.

```
S1 = ()
S2 = (18)
? = 1, 5, 7, 8, 9, 11, 12
```

8.

```
S1 = ()
S2 = ()
? = 1, 5, 7, 8, 9, 11, 12, 18
```

I had a look at my lecture slides first where I was given this example:

https://dl.dropbox.com/u/8049855/Dream%20In%20Code/Screen%20Shot%202012-08-12%20at%2022.00.10.png

First, can anyone help correct me if I'm wrong? And two, I feel I need to create a new variable to store the result, but what would I call it - S3? - In my lecture slides, there are three variables - A, B, and S.

As a side note, I also found a popular link on YouTube which discusses other sorting algorithms:

www.youtube.com/xoaxdotnet

Comment: This should be tagged as homework if it is for class.

Comment: http://penguin.ewu.edu/cscd300/Topic/AdvSorting/MergeSorts/InPlace.html

Answer (score 1):

Of course you need a new variable for the result: it is distinct from the two input variables.  And you can call it whatever you want to (except for the names already used).